# Three.js update scale object-size via view

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'm new in three.js and have a problem by scaling a object. I already looked at the documentation (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates), but i don't really understand it at all.

My Problem: By changing a HTML-select-element the CubeGeometry should be scaled in the x-direction. That is already working BUT the "old" Cube do not disappear. So i have 2 Cubes. But i want only one Cube with the current size. I hope you can understand my problem ;-)

So here is my Code from the View:

```
$(document).on('change',".configurator > form select",function(event){

    // update 3D-object - is that a nice way???
    $.getScript("/javascripts/3D-animation.js.erb", function(){
        // here comes the update
        OBJECT3D.updateObject();
    });

})
```

And here is my 3D-animation.js.erb:

```
var drawing_area;
var renderer;
var camera;
var obj;
var scene;

var OBJECT3D = {};

$(function() {

    // get drawing_area
    drawing_area = document.getElementById("canvas_wrapper");

    // initialize renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(drawing_area.clientWidth, drawing_area.clientHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1);

    // add renderer to drawing_area
    drawing_area.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // initialize camera
    camera              = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, drawing_area.clientWidth/drawing_area.clientHeight, 1, 100000);
    camera.position.z   = 1000;
    camera.position.y   = 100;
    camera.position.x   = 300;//-0.78;

    // create texture
    var texture   = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "/images/materials/texture_1.jpg" );
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );

    // create object
    var obj_form        = new THREE.CubeGeometry(250,250,250);
    var obj_material    = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture,ambient: 0x999999 } );
    OBJECT3D.obj        = new THREE.Mesh(obj_form, obj_material);

    // so what do i need here?
    OBJECT3D.obj.geometry.dynamic           = true;
    // OBJECT3D.obj.geometry.__dirtyVertices   = true;
    // OBJECT3D.obj.geometry.__dirtyNormals    = true;
    // OBJECT3D.obj.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    // create scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(camera);
    scene.add(OBJECT3D.obj);

    // create lights
    pointLight            = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
    pointLight.position.x = 400;
    pointLight.position.y = 200;
    pointLight.position.z = 1300;
    scene.add(pointLight);

    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff);
    scene.add( ambientLight );


    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    function render(){
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

        OBJECT3D.obj.rotation.y += 0.005; 
        OBJECT3D.obj.rotation.z += 0.005; 

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };


    // update object
    OBJECT3D.updateObject = function () {
        console.log("in update");
        OBJECT3D.obj.scale.x = 2.5; // SCALE
        OBJECT3D.obj.geometry.needsUpdate = true;
        //render();
    }

});
```

Sorry, if the Code is not the best one, but i'm really new in this stuff! :) hope you can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are using $.getScript method. This will load your script each time again and create a new instance of OBJECT3D.

I propose that you make sure that your code in 3D-animation.js.erb will be included and called only once upon the load of a page (include it just like any other regular javascript file) and then call your update directly like this:

```
$(document).on('change',".configurator > form select", function(event) {
    OBJECT3D.updateObject();
});
```

also, I believe you can drop following lines of code:

```
OBJECT3D.obj.geometry.needsUpdate = true;
```

and

```
OBJECT3D.obj.geometry.dynamic = true;
```